# Testcase to check if multiple files of specific pattern are present

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Want to validate if multiple files with filenames in a specific pattern are created by a function. The test case I have written is

```
describe('Sitemap', () => {
       it('it should create XML sitemap', () => {
              let language='hindi'
              return sitemapContainer.createSitemap(language).then(() => {
                   expect(fs.existsSync(`sos/sos_${language}*.xml`)).to.be.true
              });       
        })
})
```

but it fails. Which function should I use in place of fs.existsSync so that pattern could be matched . Some example files are sos_hindi_1.xml , sos_hindi_2.xml , sos_hindi_3.xml .

Answer (score 1):

`existsSync` looks for a single file, but you can think out of the box and come with a different approach.

You can instead read the entire folder so that you have a list of files, and then do your manipulations.

```js
expect(fs.readdirSync('sos/').some(file => /* your condition */)).to.be.true
```

If at least one file matches your condition, it will return `true`

### Possible solution

With a regex, you can do something like that

```js
let lan = "hindi";
var reg = new RegExp(`sos_${lan}_\\S\.xml`, 'g');
expect(fs.readdirSync('sos/').some(file => file.match(reg))).to.be.true
```